# Passing type parameter to scala meta macro/annotations

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scalameta

```
package scalaworld.macros
import scala.meta._

class Argument(arg: Int) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    println(this.structure)
    val arg = this match {
      // The argument needs to be a literal like `1` or a string like `"foobar"`.
      // You can't pass in a variable name.
      case q"new $_(${Lit(arg: Int)})"                      => arg
      // Example if you have more than one argument.
      case q"new $_(${Lit(arg: Int)}, ${Lit(foo: String)})" => arg
      case _                                                => ??? // default     value
    }
    println(s"Arg is $arg")
    defn.asInstanceOf[Stat]
  }
}
```

I would like to modify the macro above and add type parameter [A].
I tried the following but it does not compile

```
package scalaworld.macros
import scala.meta._

class Argument2[A](arg: A) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    println(this.structure)
    val arg = this match {
      case q"new $_(${Lit(arg: A)})"                      => arg
      case q"new $_(${Lit(arg: A)}, ${Lit(foo: String)})" => arg
      case _                                              => ???
    }
    println(s"Arg is $arg")
    defn.asInstanceOf[Stat]
  }
}
```

Comment: i am just trying to do something similar to what is described here https://github.com/scalameta/sips/blob/3520d5c761abfdfeff66d396456791971795f6af/sips/pending/_posts/2016-09-09-inline-meta.md#inlinemeta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments passed into macro annotations are passed in as meta trees.

Although literals such as Int/Double/String can be extracted via the `Lit()` extractor. this is not the case for other things.

When parsed in meta

- `@someMacro(1)` becomes `@someMacro(Lit(1))`
- `@someMacro("Foo")` becomes `@someMacro(Lit("Foo"))`

Everything else gets passed as it would be normally

- `@someMacro(foo)` becomes `@someMacro(Term.Name("foo"))`
- `@someMacro(Option(2))` becomes `@someMacro(Term.Apply(Term.Name("Option"), Seq(Lit(2))))`

This means you do not have runtime access to this thing. You cannot even instantiate an object properly without the Semantic Api to resolve symbols etc. It *may* be possible in scalameta 2 and paradise 4, but it definately is not possible now. What you could do, is make a runtime pattern match to check the value.

I do some similar things here (Note this is very WIP):
https://github.com/DavidDudson/Elysium/blob/master/gen/src/main/scala/nz/daved/elysium/gen/MacroAnnotation.scala

See specifically https://github.com/DavidDudson/Elysium/blob/master/gen/src/main/scala/nz/daved/elysium/gen/MacroAnnotation.scala#L149

Note: This means that at runtime (which just so happens to be compile time in that example), if the arg is passed in of an incorrect type, a runtime exception

Comment: Thank you @David Dudson
I am getting an error while trying to compile this class
https://github.com/DavidDudson/Elysium/blob/master/gen/src/main/scala/nz/daved/elysium/gen/MacroAnnotation.scala
can you provide the paradise_2.11.8-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ?
`[error] /Users/batemady/tools/scala/samples/meta/scalameta-tutorial/src/main/scala/scala/meta/serialiser/MacroAnnotation.scala:14: ; expected but def found
[error]     val newStat = q"$compileTimeOnly inline def apply(a: Any): Any = meta { ..$inMetaBlockStats }"`

Comment: I get the following error while trying to compile the whole Elysium project
`[error] Missing required plugin: macroparadise`

Comment: I finally got it compile sucessfuly by just commenting in the line adding the Paradise plugin

Comment: That project is using this PR https://github.com/scalameta/paradise/pulls.

Elysium should not compile without that PR as it deals with macros generating other macros

Comment: What i would like todo  is using type parameters passed to the macro while expanding. In the following macro i can print the parameter passed to the macro, but dont know how to use and replace T and L with the passed in
while generating the returned tree( defn )


`import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

class tparam[T, L] extends StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    assert(T.toString == "Int")
    assert(L.toString == "String")
    println(T.toString )
    println(L.toString)
    defn
  }
}
`